# Why ion-infinite-scroll keeps calling on scrolling in Android?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using 'ion-infinite-scroll' in html to load more items from server for this i am using below code

```
<ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" on-infinite="getListOfAreas()" distance="1%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Here, getListOfAreas() function is called when I scroll screen to bottom and it fetches data from server.This is getListOfAreas() function defined on controller

```
$scope.getListOfAreas = function (shoudlShowLoader) {
AreaBusiness.getAreasListing(shoudlShowLoader, function(serviceResponse) {
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        if (serviceResponse != null) {
            var isSuccess = serviceResponse.Success;
            if (isSuccess) {

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

On browser, i have debugged some how

```
$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
```

above line of code keeps calling and spinner keep rotating.I don't know the reason. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');` only lets ionic know that the current page of data has been fetched and that it's safe to now fetch the next page. This does not indicate that all data has finished loading.

Looks like the official recommendation is to add an `ng-if` to the scroll delegate and remove it from dom once there is not more data to load.

Example:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    ng-if="moreDataCanBeLoaded()"
    icon="ion-loading-c"
    on-infinite="loadMoreData()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Comment: I want that spinner to be stopped once web service call is finished. For that purpose i used $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete'); on service call back funtion weather the response is success or not. Isn't it a good idea to achieve that. Please rectify me If I am using this approach in a wrong way. And one more thing, I have already used the same approach in another controller and on that controller it is working fine as expected. Spinner stops when service call back recieved.

Comment: Like i mentioned in the answer, as long as the `ion-infinite-scroll` delegate is in dom, and it has finished loading the last page as indicated by `scroll.infiniteScrollComplete`, the spinner keeps on spinning.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, after spending sometime. The issue which I found, I was not adding those elements into the list which were to be shown on UI. So, list was not being updated on controller that is why it kept calling.So I updated my code and added those fetched items from service to list associated to ui as mentioned in my below code

```
$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
if (serviceResponse != null) {
    var isSuccess = serviceResponse.Success;
        if (isSuccess) {        
            if ($scope.areas !=  undefined && $scope.areas.length > 0) {
                pushDataToPOIList(serviceResponse.PointOfInterestData);
            } else {
                $scope.areas = serviceResponse.PointOfInterestData;
            }
```

pushDataToVehiclesList() method I added that is pushing new data into list to update list and on UI as well. This helped me to sort out the problem.